# How to output object with DBMS output in oracle from function return object in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am written a function and object for employee details. The function returns an object for a specific employee and I want to show the result via DBMS output from the returned object. But I can't do this. Please help me to solve this problem.

Types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMP_DETAILS_OBJ AS OBJECT(
  EMPID NUMBER,
  ENAME VARCHAR2(100),
  DESIGNATION VARCHAR2(100),
  DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(50),
  JOIN_DATE DATE,
  COUNTRY VARCHAR2(50),
  REGION VARCHAR2(30)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMP_DETAILS_TABLE IS TABLE OF EMP_DETAILS_OBJ
/
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GETEMPLOYEE_INFO(SEARCH_EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER)
RETURN EMP_DETAILS_TABLE IS
  EMPLOYEEID NUMBER;
  EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(100);
  DESIGNATION VARCHAR2(100);
  DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(50);
  JOIN_DATE DATE;
  COUNTRY VARCHAR2(50);
  REGION VARCHAR2(30);
  EMP_DETAILS EMP_DETAILS_TABLE := EMP_DETAILS_TABLE();
BEGIN
  EMP_DETAILS.EXTEND();

  SELECT EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    EMP.FIRST_NAME||' '||EMP.LAST_NAME,
    EMPJOB.JOB_TITLE,
    DEPT.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
    EMP.HIRE_DATE,
    CNTRY.COUNTRY_NAME,
    RGN.REGION_NAME
  INTO EMPLOYEEID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, DESIGNATION, DEPARTMENT, JOIN_DATE,
    COUNTRY, REGION
  FROM EMPLOYEES EMP
  LEFT OUTER JOIN JOBS EMPJOB ON EMPJOB.JOB_ID = EMP.JOB_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPARTMENTS DEPT ON DEPT.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMP.DEPARTMENT_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATIONS LOC ON LOC.LOCATION_ID = DEPT.LOCATION_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN COUNTRIES CNTRY ON CNTRY.COUNTRY_ID = LOC.COUNTRY_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN REGIONS RGN ON RGN.REGION_ID = CNTRY.REGION_ID
  WHERE EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID = SEARCH_EMPLOYEE_ID ;

  EMP_DETAILS(1) := EMP_DETAILS_OBJ(EMPLOYEEID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, DESIGNATION,
    DEPARTMENT, JOIN_DATE, COUNTRY, REGION);

  RETURN EMP_DETAILS;
END;
/
```

Calls:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE 
  --EMP_DETAILS EMP_DETAILS_TABLE :=EMP_DETAILS_TABLE();
  EMP_OBJ EMP_DETAILS_OBJ;
BEGIN
  EMP_OBJ :=GETEMPLOYEE_INFO(100);
  --EMP_OBJ :=EMP_DETAILS_OBJ(EMP_DETAILS.EMPID,EMP_DETAILS.ENAME,EMP_DETAILS.DESIGNATION,EMP_DETAILS.DEPARTMENT,EMP_DETAILS.JOIN_DATE,EMP_DETAILS.COUNTRY,EMP_DETAILS.REGION);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE_ID: '||EMP_OBJ.EMPID);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE_NAME: ');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DESIGNATION: ');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DEPARTMENT: ');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('JOIN DATE: '||EMP_DETAILS.JOIN_DATE);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COUNTRY: '||EMP_DETAILS.COUNTRY);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('REGION: '||EMP_DETAILS.REGION); 
END;
/

SELECT GETEMPLOYEE_INFO(100) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: To answer the question we would need more information eg what error you are getting or what happens when you run this.  The one thing that jumps out at me is your function returns a table of objects and the variable that you are putting this into is a single object not a table of objects.

Comment: When I run the query to see the result in pl/sql then a error show that EMPID not declare. But I declare a object already. So how can i show output in object details in DBMS OUTPUT by calling the GETEMPLOYEE_INFO function

Comment: Where is the declaration of these variable in your function `EMPLOYEEID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,DESIGNATION,DEPARTMENT,JOIN_DATE,COUNTRY,REGION` .Oracle refers to these declaration.

Comment: The function return a object and the object declare first

Comment: @XING - scroll right on the `create or replace function` line *8-) The whole thing is just badly formatted...

Comment: @NahidHasan - please format your code to make it more readable. Why is your function returning a table of records when you pass in a single ID and only create one object - why isn't it retuning an `emo_details_obj`, as the anonymous block currently expects!? Also please include the error stack you get for the code you posted as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

> The function returns an object for a specific employee

No it doesn't. It returns a table containing a single object. If you make your function return an object instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GETEMPLOYEE_INFO(SEARCH_EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER)
RETURN EMP_DETAILS_OBJ IS
  EMPLOYEEID NUMBER;
  EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(100);
  DESIGNATION VARCHAR2(100);
  DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(50);
  JOIN_DATE DATE;
  COUNTRY VARCHAR2(50);
  REGION VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  SELECT EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    EMP.FIRST_NAME||' '||EMP.LAST_NAME,
    EMPJOB.JOB_TITLE,
    DEPT.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
    EMP.HIRE_DATE,
    CNTRY.COUNTRY_NAME,
    RGN.REGION_NAME
  INTO EMPLOYEEID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, DESIGNATION, DEPARTMENT, JOIN_DATE,
    COUNTRY, REGION
  FROM EMPLOYEES EMP
  LEFT OUTER JOIN JOBS EMPJOB ON EMPJOB.JOB_ID = EMP.JOB_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPARTMENTS DEPT ON DEPT.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMP.DEPARTMENT_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATIONS LOC ON LOC.LOCATION_ID = DEPT.LOCATION_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN COUNTRIES CNTRY ON CNTRY.COUNTRY_ID = LOC.COUNTRY_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN REGIONS RGN ON RGN.REGION_ID = CNTRY.REGION_ID
  WHERE EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID = SEARCH_EMPLOYEE_ID ;

  RETURN EMP_DETAILS_OBJ(EMPLOYEEID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, DESIGNATION,
    DEPARTMENT, JOIN_DATE, COUNTRY, REGION);
END;
/
```

That is, removing the `EMP_DETAILS` declaration, and returning a new object directly (instead of assigning that object to the table and returning the table).

Then your anonymous block works, with the reference names fixed too:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE 
  EMP_OBJ EMP_DETAILS_OBJ;
BEGIN
  EMP_OBJ := GETEMPLOYEE_INFO(100);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE_ID: ' ||EMP_OBJ.EMPID);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE_NAME: ' ||EMP_OBJ.ENAME);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DESIGNATION: ' ||EMP_OBJ.DESIGNATION);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DEPARTMENT: ' ||EMP_OBJ.DEPARTMENT);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('JOIN DATE: ' ||EMP_OBJ.JOIN_DATE);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COUNTRY: ' ||EMP_OBJ.COUNTRY);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('REGION: ' ||EMP_OBJ.REGION); 
END;
/

EMPLOYEE_ID: 100
EMPLOYEE_NAME: Steven King
DESIGNATION: President
DEPARTMENT: Executive
JOIN DATE: 17-JUN-87
COUNTRY: United States of America
REGION: Americas

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You could simplify the function even more by creating the object as part of the query, so you don't need local variables for each column/field:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GETEMPLOYEE_INFO(SEARCH_EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER)
RETURN EMP_DETAILS_OBJ IS
  L_EMP_DETAILS_OBJ EMP_DETAILS_OBJ;
BEGIN
  SELECT EMP_DETAILS_OBJ(EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    EMP.FIRST_NAME||' '||EMP.LAST_NAME,
    EMPJOB.JOB_TITLE,
    DEPT.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
    EMP.HIRE_DATE,
    CNTRY.COUNTRY_NAME,
    RGN.REGION_NAME)
  INTO L_EMP_DETAILS_OBJ
  FROM EMPLOYEES EMP
  LEFT OUTER JOIN JOBS EMPJOB ON EMPJOB.JOB_ID = EMP.JOB_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPARTMENTS DEPT ON DEPT.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMP.DEPARTMENT_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATIONS LOC ON LOC.LOCATION_ID = DEPT.LOCATION_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN COUNTRIES CNTRY ON CNTRY.COUNTRY_ID = LOC.COUNTRY_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN REGIONS RGN ON RGN.REGION_ID = CNTRY.REGION_ID
  WHERE EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID = SEARCH_EMPLOYEE_ID ;

  RETURN L_EMP_DETAILS_OBJ;
END;
/
```